# Заменить некоторые символы в String

Tags: java

Вечер добрый. Очень буду рад помощи. Присутствует к примеру такой безобразный HTML код

> ```
>   <a href="/index.php">
>      <img src="/templates/r_first_to_j/images/logo.png" />
> </a>
> ```
>
> </div>

```
<div id="main_menu">
  <div id="horizmenu-surround">
    <ul class="menutop level1" >
                        <li class="item101 active root" >Тестовый текс лорем ипсум
                    <a class="item" href="/ru/"  >
                <span>
```

Я хотел убрать все табуляции слева(в начале каждой строки). Хочу реализовать это в способ удаления пробелов, если их стоит подряд больше одного. Важно, чтоб удаляло пробелы, табуляции таких образом, чтоб они оставались нетронутыми в обычном тексте и внутри тагов.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: google "html beautifier" -> http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/

Comment: в среде java

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что @romashechka говорит не о Java, а о JavaScript :))

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [trim()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm)